# Autolisp entmake missing parameter

Tags: dxf, autolisp

I'm using Autolisp to create an entity (a plugin component).

[Custom component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zibhj.jpg)

First use `entget` to collect data of an existing entity, and it shows me this list:

```
((-1 . <name: 24df3f09820>)
(0 . "TCH_ARROW")
(330 . <name: 24df3da69f0>)
(5 . "2B2")
(100 . "AcDbEntity")
(67 . 0)
(410 . "Model")
(8 . "DIM_SYMB")
(100 . "TDbEntity")
(46 . 0.0)
(47 . 100.0)
(68 . 1)
(100 . "TDbSymbWithText")
(7 . "_TCH_DIM")
(40 . 3.5)
(52 . 0.0)
(410 . "PUB_TEXT")
(100 . "TDbSymbArrow")
(70 . 2)
(11 0.0 0.0 0.0)
(1 . "ABC")
(41 . 3.0)
(10 3241.87 3026.46 0.0)
(50 . 0.0)
(10 870.38 2088.79 0.0)
(50 . 0.0)
(71 . 0))
```

But then I removed `-1` and `330`, and feed these data into `entmake`, like this:

```
(entmakex (list
  '(0 . "TCH_ARROW")
  '(5 . "2B2")
  '(100 . "AcDbEntity")
  '(67 . 0)
  '(410 . "Model")
  '(8 . "DIM_SYMB")
  '(100 . "TDbEntity")
  '(46 . 0.0)
  '(47 . 100.0)
  '(68 . 1)
  '(100 . "TDbSymbWithText")
  '(7 . "_TCH_DIM")
  '(40 . 3.5)
  '(52 . 0.0)
  '(410 . "PUB_TEXT")
  '(100 . "TDbSymbArrow")
  '(70 . 2)
  '(11 0.0 0.0 0.0)
  '(1 . "ABC")
  '(41 . 3.0)
  '(10 3241.87 3026.46 0.0)
  '(50 . 0.0)
  '(10 870.38 2088.79 0.0)
  '(50 . 0.0)
  '(71 . 0)
))
```

I'm expecting a copy of the original one but... it failed and returned "nil"...

I think some required data was missing, so what could be missing? I also realized `entget` didn't return all attributes, how can I collect all the data of an entity instead of guessing which data is required?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For the first glance problem may be caused by

```
  '(5 . "2B2")
```

Let the application create own handle for each entity, just remove this.